# Do Doctor Who and Star Trek occur in the same universe?

Tags: star-trek, doctor-who, crossovers

In a [few comic books](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Assimilation%C2%B2_%28comic_story%29) the Doctor has, in his fourth and eleventh incarnations landed on the Enterprise. Regardless of whether Kirk or Picard he has entered the trek universe but in "The Impossible Astronaut" an elderly woman asks a member of The Silence if his costume is from the Star Trek show.

My question is, can the Star Trek universe and 'Whoniverse' coincide with each other?
Also if they can be linked together could the aliens from Star Trek appear on Doctor Who? 
I feel as though mixing them would give a larger audience to both shows. Would there be as many legal complications in using the aliens like romulins, volcan, borgs etc... in Doctor who?

Comment: The short answer is no. Crossover comics are common but it's rare (practically unheard of in fact) for internationally networked shows to cross each other due to rights issues.

Comment: “I feel as though mixing them would give a larger audience to both shows” — they sure are [starved for viewers](http://news.drwho-online.co.uk/The-Day-Of-The-Doctor-Finalised-Viewing-Figures.aspx) as it is.

Comment: In the sixties the batman tv show  did a special that crossed over with the green hornet

Comment: Those shows where produced by the same company. For just one example of the difficulty of crossover - The Avengers movie was missing Spider-man and the Fantastic Four.

Comment: @HorusKol Not to mention any mutants

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Comics are not canon.

Not that *Doctor Who* has anything we can call canon, but comics aren't even top drawer fan canon. Since the show is often unconcerned about making sense *inside itself*, we shouldn't expect consistency between the show and its other off-screen products.

### That said, the show does have a very unusual relationship with the "real world."

In fact, [one Seventh Doctor story set in 1963](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Remembrance_of_the_Daleks_%28TV_story%29) had a television set announce the first episode of *Doctor Who* (it was cut off quickly enough to be hand-waved as something else, but the intent was clear). So make of that what you will.

### However, the chances of the two TV shows having an actual crossover event is minimal.

Crossover events between TV shows are rare, and almost always reserved for shows which are both owned, produced, and distributed by the same companies. The legal mess alone wouldn't be worth it, because both shows are aiming for syndication and that means the crossover episodes would have to meet all the legal requirements for the actors, writers, producers, etc., of both shows *and* both syndication companies.

Comics crossovers exist to give us a chance to experience what the shows can't do.

Comment: Do you happen to know which episode of the Seventh Doctor's run that TV incident occurred?

Comment: It was in [*Remembrance of the Daleks*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Remembrance_of_the_Daleks_(TV_story)), in the boarding house belonging to Mike Smith's mother. The TV is on in the sitting room, though no one is paying attention to it. It says, "This is BBC Television, the time is quarter past five and Saturday viewing continues with an adventure in the new science fiction series Doc-" and then the scene changes.

Comment: A related question and answers: [Television crossover episodes between networks?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/17270)